# background css animation using keyframe stop the contact form functionalities

Tags: html, css, forms, css-animations

I'm trying to make work a submition form using bootstrap + wp with a animated background using only css,  the animation is working fine, but when i create the form into the same div container not working at all. I was Trying z-index css property, but can't fix the problem, it look like the animation is  overlay the form. I really don't know how can i fix. I want to find the way the form work properly and with the animated background.

```css
.space {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1B2735;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1B2735 0%, #090A0F 100%);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

.stars > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.stars .stars-back {
  top: -50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 30px, #eee, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 40px 70px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(1px 1px at 90px 40px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 160px 120px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  animation: stars 4s infinite linear;
}

.stars .stars-middle {
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(3px 3px at 50px 160px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 90px 40px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 130px 80px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  animation: stars 2.5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes stars {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron space">
  <div class="stars">
    <div class="stars-back"></div>
    <div class="stars-middle"></div>
    <div class="stars-front"></div>
  </div>
  <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <p class="form-control-static">email@example.com</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm identity</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is by wrapping your code in a parent div and setting its position to relative, then set your form element to absolute and place it using left and or top... This will take the element out of the normal document flow.

```css
.space {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1B2735;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1B2735 0%, #090A0F 100%);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
}

.form {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40%;
}

.stars>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.stars .stars-back {
  top: -50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 30px, #eee, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 40px 70px, #fff, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 90px 40px, #fff, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 160px 120px, #ddd, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  animation: stars 4s infinite linear;
}

.stars .stars-middle {
  background-image: radial-gradient(3px 3px at 50px 160px, #ddd, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 90px 40px, #fff, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 130px 80px, #fff, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  animation: stars 2.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes stars {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="jumbotron space">
    <div class="stars">
      <div class="stars-back"></div>
      <div class="stars-middle"></div>
      <div class="stars-front"></div>
    </div>
    <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
    <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
  </div>
  <form class="form-inline form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
      <p class="form-control-static">email@example.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm identity</button>
  </form>
</div>
```